# ArcObjects Workspaces with spaces

Tags: arcobjects, workspace

I am programming with ArcObjects and trying to output a raster to a folder path that contains spaces. Before creating the raster I am trying to validate that the destination path is valid. The following call to IsWorkspace() returns false when the path has spaces. Is this by design or a problem? How should one test that a folder is a valid file-based raster workspace?

```vb
Dim aType As Type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriDataSourcesRaster.RasterWorkspaceFactory")
Dim obj As System.Object = Activator.CreateInstance(aType)
Dim pWSF As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IWorkspaceFactory = obj
return pWSF.IsWorkspace("C:\MyGISData\My Output Folder")
```

Comment: So the code returns true if the workspace location doesn't contain spaces?

Comment: Yes that's right. Returns True when there are no spaces. The strange thing is that a path with spaces is valid and the remainder of my code works with a path containing spaces. Raster gets generated in folder correctly.

Comment: That looks like a bug to me. Placing the path in quotes is working for all the rest of your code. What if you try making the path a variable and passing that instead of a direct string? i.e. dim sPath = "C:\MyGISData\My Output Folder" return pWSF.IsWorkspace(sPath)

Comment: I am actually using the variable approach (I chopped up the code a bit to post it here). And I just tried wrapping the path in quotes. I've also tried appending a trailing slash. No joy.

Comment: I just did a quick test with 10.1 ... 
`IWorkspaceFactory.IsWorkspace` returns true for both `D:\projects\Grid` and `D:\projects\Gr id` ... but only if there are actually rasters in the folder.  (an info subfolder is not sufficient).

Perhaps a folder is not considered a raster workspace unless it actually contains some raster datasets.